# Creating a quiz with text input rather than multiple choice

Tags: html, input

I need to create an on-line quiz in where the user can type in the answer. There are plenty of multiple choice quizzes out there, but I can't seem to find any that use input from the user?

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to write awesome regex and somehow get the user to enter something you can expect by engineering your questions well. There is a reason people use multiple choices as input.